# apex:form not getting displyed on button click

Tags: visualforce

I have a vf page which has a button named "proceed" on line 154. what it should do is to display the form2 which is apex:form and hide form which is also apex:form.

I am trying to do it using javascript  $j('form[id$=form2]').show(); and  $j('form[id$=form]').hide();

This method is not working.

Can anyone please help me as to why this does not work
`

```
<apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.CKEditorAirco, 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}" />




<script >


function hideContactList(){
    $j('form[id$=form2]').show();
    $j('form[id$=form]').hide();
}

function back(){
    showSpinner();
    CallApexMethodBack();
    if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one) ) {              
        //javascript:sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/page?Account=');
    }else{
        //window.location.href ='/apex/page?Account=';
    }              
}
function back2(){
    showSpinner();
    CallApexMethodBack2();
    if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one) ) {              
        //javascript:sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/page?Account=');
    }else{
        //window.location.href ='/apex/page?Account=';
    }              
}
function selectToEmail(){
    showSpinner();
    CallApexMethodSelectToEmail();
    if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one) ) {              
        //javascript:sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/page?Account=');
    }else{
        //window.location.href ='/apex/page?Account=';
    }              
}
function sendTemplates(){
    showSpinner();
    CallApexMethodSendTemplates();
    if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one) ) {              
        //javascript:sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/page?Account=');
    }else{
        //window.location.href ='/apex/page?Account=';
    }              
}
function showSpinner(){
    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
}
function hideSpinner(){
    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<style>
    tr.spaceUnder > td{
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    }    
    .cError{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #c00;
    text-align: center
    }
    .title{
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: #2e4153;
    font-size: 18px;
    }   
</style>
<style>
    .slds-form-element{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
</style>

<apex:slds />

<body>    
    <!-- REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
    <div class="slds">    
        <div class="slds-spinner_container" style="display:none;" id="loader">
            <div class="slds-spinner slds-spinner--large" aria-hidden="false" role="alert">
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- MASTHEAD -->
        <div class="slds-text-heading--large slds-text-align--left" style="margin-bottom:50px"> </div>

        <div class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-text-align--left" style="margin-bottom:30px"> </div>
        <!-- / MASTHEAD -->    

        <!-- PRIMARY CONTENT WRAPPER -->
        <div class="myapp">

            <div class="slds-container--center slds-container--small">

                <apex:form id="form" rendered="{!emailNotSelected}">
                    <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethodSelectToEmail" action="{!selectToEmail}" rerender="toEmailsOutPutText, messagePanel" oncomplete="hideSpinner(),hideContactList()"/>
                    <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethodBack" action="{!Back}" oncomplete="hideSpinner()"/>

                    <apex:outputPanel id="emailSetPanel">

                        <apex:pageBlock >
                            <div id="emailErrorDiv" class="cError" style="display:none;">Error: No Contact selected. <br/> NO Select at least one Contact in Quotation to proceed to send mail.</div>

                            <div class="title"><b>Customer Contacts:</b></div>
                            <div>&nbsp;</div>
                            <apex:pageBlockTable width="50%" value="{!contactInnerClassList}" var="c" id="tblResults">                       
                                <apex:column >
                                    <apex:facet name="header"><apex:outputPanel >Select</apex:outputPanel></apex:facet>
                                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}"/>    
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column >
                                    <apex:facet name="header"><apex:outputPanel >Name</apex:outputPanel></apex:facet>
                                    <apex:outputtext >{!c.name}</apex:outputtext>     
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column >
                                    <apex:facet name="header"><apex:outputPanel >Email</apex:outputPanel></apex:facet>
                                    <apex:outputtext >{!c.email}</apex:outputtext>    
                                </apex:column>
                            </apex:pageBlockTable>                         
                        </apex:pageBlock>

                        <div>&nbsp;</div>
                        <div>&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="title"><b>Internal Users:</b></div>
                        <div>&nbsp;</div>

                        <apex:pageBlock id="pbselect">
                            <div align="left">
                                <apex:selectList id="myselect" value="{!internalUsersSelected}" multiselect="true" size="10">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                                </apex:selectList>
                            </div>
                        </apex:pageBlock>          

                        <div align="center">
                            <div>&nbsp;</div>       
                            <span id="proceed2" >
                                <div class="slds-text-align--center">
                                    <a class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="selectToEmail();">Proceed</a>
                                    <a class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="back();">Go Back</a>
                                </div>                
                            </span>
                        </div>    

                    </apex:outputPanel>             
                </apex:form>  
            </div>

            <apex:form id="form2" style="display:none;" > 
                <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethodSendTemplates" action="{!sendTemplates}" oncomplete="hideSpinner()"/>
                <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethodBack2" action="{!Back}" oncomplete="hideSpinner()"/>

                <apex:outputPanel id="emailOutputPanel">

                    <table width="100%">
                        <b>
                            <tr class="spaceUnder">
                                <td width="10%"><b>To: </b></td>
                                <td width="90%"><apex:outputText value="{!toEmails}" id="toEmailsOutPutText"/></td>            
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="spaceUnder">
                                <td width="10%"><b>Cc: </b></td>
                                <td width="90%"><apex:inputTextarea value="{!ccemails}" style="width:100%"/></td>             
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="spaceUnder">
                                <td width="10%"><b>Email Template: </b></td>
                                <td width="90%">
                                    <apex:selectList value="{!tmpltName}" id="Template" size="1" label="Email Template">
                                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!templates}"/>
                                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!populatetemplate}"/>
                                    </apex:selectList>                 
                                </td>             
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="spaceUnder">
                                <td width="10%"><b>Email Subject: </b></td>
                                <td width="90%"><apex:inputText value="{!emailSubject}" style="width:100%" /></td>             
                            </tr>                         
                            <tr class="spaceUnder">
                                <td width="10%"><b>Email Body: </b></td>
                                <td width="90%"><apex:inputtextarea value="{!emailBody}" id="Body1" styleClass="ckeditor"/></td>           
                            </tr>           
                        </b>                        
                    </table>

                    <div class="slds-container--center slds-container--small">
                        <div>&nbsp;</div>
                        <div>&nbsp;</div>
                        <span id="send" >
                            <div class="slds-text-align--center">
                                <a class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="sendTemplates();">Send Email</a>
                                <a class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="back2();">Go Back</a>
                            </div>                
                        </span>                
                    </div>   

                </apex:outputPanel>       
            </apex:form>            
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!emailSelected}">
                <script>
                $j('form[id$=form2]').show();
                </script>
            </apex:outputPanel>           

        </div>
        <!-- / PRIMARY CONTENT WRAPPER -->    


        <apex:outputPanel id="thePricePanel">        
            <!-- Custom error message -->
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!warningFlag}">
                <div class="slds-notify_container">
                    <div class="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--alert-texture" role="alert">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-notify__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close">
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon">
                                <use href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Info</span>
                        <h2>{!warningMsg}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>                         
                </div>    
            </apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!errorFlag}">
                <div class="slds-notify_container">
                    <div class="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--error slds-theme--alert-texture" role="alert">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-notify__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close">
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon">
                                <use href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Error</span>
                        <h2>
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--small slds-m-right--x-small">
                                <use href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#ban')}"></use>
                            </svg>{!errorMsg}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>                         
                </div>    
            </apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!successFlag}">
                <div class="slds-notify_container">
                    <div class="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--success slds-theme--alert-texture" role="alert">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-notify__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close">
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon">
                                <use href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Success</span>
                        <h2>
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--small slds-m-right--x-small">
                                <use href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/assets/icons/custom-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#custom19')}"></use>               
                            </svg>{!successMsg}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>                 
                </div>    
            </apex:outputpanel>
            <!-- Custom error message -->
        </apex:outputPanel>


    </div>

    <!-- / REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->    
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.SLDSDynamicLookupScript}"/>

</body>
```

`

Comment: try with  $j('form[id$=form2]').css({'display':'block'});  for showing $j('form[id$=form2]').css({'display':'none'}); for hiding

Comment: Hi Dhanik, I tried it, but didn't work.

Comment: What happens when you execute hideContactList in the JS console? Does that work

Comment: It goes into hideContactList () as i can see the alerts that had put inside. But it does not show or hide the apex:forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using var x = document.getElementById('FORMID');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }

Thanks to Sakthivel Madesh